# What are double colons :: in a shell script?

Tags: bash, coding-style

What is double colon `::` in shell scripts? like this piece of script:

```
function guess_built_binary_path {
  local hyperkube_path=$(kube::util::find-binary "hyperkube")
  if [[ -z "${hyperkube_path}" ]]; then
    return
  fi
  echo -n "$(dirname "${hyperkube_path}")"
}
```

I found it in here:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/hack/local-up-cluster.sh

Comment: What are the odds that i was going through same file (exploring k8s source code) and had the same doubt and google got me here :)

Comment: @ManishBansal the same here !!

Comment: I am here for the same reason

Comment: Even I'm for the same reason :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `::` is just a ***Naming Convention*** for *function names*. Is a coding-style such as [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) or [CamelCase](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)

The convention for *Function names* in shell style commonly is:

> Lower-case, with underscores to separate words. Separate libraries
>   with ::. Parentheses are required after the function name. The keyword
>   function is optional, but must be used consistently throughout a
>   project.

You can check [here](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml).

Answer (score 5):

Although it seems like Bash allows putting colons in function names, [this behaviour is not standardized by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_05):

> The function is named *fname*; the application shall ensure that it is a name (see XBD [*Name*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_235)) .... An implementation may allow other characters in a function name as an extension.

[3.235 Name](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_235) says it's:

> a word consisting solely of underscores, digits, and alphabetics from the [portable character set](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap06.html#tag_06_01).

Answer (score 2):

It's nothing, these colons are part of the command names apparently.  You can verify yourself by creating and running a command with `:` in the name.  The shell by default will autoescape them and its all perfectly legal.