# What does :: do in a shell script?

Tags: bash, sh

```
read answer 
ans=${answer::1}
```

What does the operator :: do?

I thought it allowed touppercase a letter but im not sure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are double colons :: in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558080/what-are-double-colons-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: @koto No, that's a completely different context.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see what it does:

```bash
$ answer="abcde"
$ echo ${answer::1}
a
```

It seems to print the first letter. Why is that?

The expansion `${var:offset:length}` gives a *substring* starting at the zero-based `offset` for `length` characters.

Both `offset` and `length` are arithmetic expressions, and apparently an empty offset evaluates as zero.

Full details at [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)